# Catch specifics values with php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I need to catch/separate some specific data values ​​with php. It seems that in php such thing as preg_match(). But did not succeed. I will show a small fraction of the data I'm working. The original file has more than 320 thousand letters.

```
129/09/20031820252310112414060213090516030,005BA15446454880725759349.765,82689,8410,004,002,000,000,000,00PRSPSPSP206/10/20032315050412162006111924010913070,001SP184623281252478188596.323,701.388,9510,004,002,000,000,000,00313/10/20032023120806010711140416100917240,002SP158689796244608211400.623,702.173,3610,004,002,000,000,000,00SP420/10/20031605252423081202171801100419130,001MT2589569123912706657902.226,021.498,7210,004,002,000,000,000,00527/10/20031513200211240916042325120819010,002BA47214736195636860992380.017,55687,4910,004,002,000,000,000,00MS603/11/20032319010507211610152506021204170,002RJ39314242162320888301489.140,061.066,8310,004,002,000,000,000,00RS
```

I need these data are separated, like that. Can be in an array, or a .txt file.

```
29/09/2003182025231011241406021309051603,
06/10/2003231505041216200611192401091307,
13/10/2003202312080601071114041610091724,
20/10/2003160525242308120217180110041913,
27/10/2003151320021124091604232512081901,
03/11/2003231901050721161015250602120417,
```

These data there is a pattern to get values. The value /20 would be the key so he could choose looped values ​​because it is the default on this data.

If the preg_match() had worked it would take the values ​​based on the value /20, would use the substr() positive and negative to select the scope of selecting each value found, so that after this amount found is played on an array or on a .txt file. I've tried array_search(), but it seems that it brings bolean response (TRUE or FALSE). I also tried to use explode, however the value /20 disappears and thus lose the enter key to search.

I'm really lost, I'm looking for days and thought someone could give me a path that problem. Is there some other command in php to help me in this problem?

Comment: Is it possible that this is simple CSV data? If not, do you know the exact structure?

Comment: @JensA.Koch the data comes in an .html file, so I picked up this file in php and took all the tags with strip_tags(), leaving only the data values, so to put it all together because I had a lot of empty space between the numbers I used a str_replace(). And finally I threw it in a .txt file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps you

```
$exp = "/[\\d]{2}[\\/][\\d]{2}[\\/](.*?),/"; 
$data = "129/09/20031820252310112414060213090516030,005BA15446454880725759349.765,82689,8410,004,002,000,000,000,00PRSPSPSP206/10/20032315050412162006111924010913070,001SP184623281252478188596.323,701.388,9510,004,002,000,000,000,00313/10/20032023120806010711140416100917240,002SP158689796244608211400.623,702.173,3610,004,002,000,000,000,00SP420/10/20031605252423081202171801100419130,001MT2589569123912706657902.226,021.498,7210,004,002,000,000,000,00527/10/20031513200211240916042325120819010,002BA47214736195636860992380.017,55687,4910,004,002,000,000,000,00MS603/11/20032319010507211610152506021204170,002RJ39314242162320888301489.140,061.066,8310,004,002,000,000,000,00RS\n"; 

preg_match_all($exp, $data, $result);
print_r($result);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 29/09/20031820252310112414060213090516030,
            [1] => 06/10/20032315050412162006111924010913070,
            [2] => 13/10/20032023120806010711140416100917240,
            [3] => 20/10/20031605252423081202171801100419130,
            [4] => 27/10/20031513200211240916042325120819010,
            [5] => 03/11/20032319010507211610152506021204170,
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20031820252310112414060213090516030
            [1] => 20032315050412162006111924010913070
            [2] => 20032023120806010711140416100917240
            [3] => 20031605252423081202171801100419130
            [4] => 20031513200211240916042325120819010
            [5] => 20032319010507211610152506021204170
        )

)
```

Comment: This worked. I did not know preg_match() would be that complicated, even more that there is a preg_match_all(). Thank you so much.